# Multiple table connections query

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables with multiple connections, for example:

First table: Tbl_Flights, it has fields `City_From` and `City_To`, containing city's key.
Also, there is a table called `Tbl_Cities`, which has unique counter field and field for city name.

How to create a query which will possible to print out all the flights from table `Tbl_Flights` with departure and arrival city names, like:

```
From               To
------------------------------
Moscow             New York
Amsterdam          Paris
Helsinki           Tallin
```

Does double `INNER JOIN` solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does double INNER JOIN solve the problem?

**Yes, it does.** But they are two `INNER JOIN`s to the same table `Cities`, so that you can select the `CiteName` column into two different columns `From`, `to`.

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  f.FlightName,
  FromCities.cityName "From",
  ToCities.CityName "To"
FROM Tbl_Flights f
INNER JOIN Cities FromCities ON f.City_From = FromCities.CityID
INNER JOIN Cities ToCities   ON f.City_To   = ToCities.CityID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2be0/3)

This will give you:

```
| FLIGHTNAME |      FROM |       TO |
-------------------------------------
|    Flight1 |    Moscow | New York |
|    Flight2 | Amsterdam |    Paris |
|    Flight3 |  Helsinki |   Tallin |
```

Comment: what if all cities "from" and "to" are in the same table?

Comment: @vard - Yes I assumed that they are in the same table `Cities` see my edit.

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal, if Cities is a table, what means construction `INNER JOIN Cities FromCities ON ...` ?

Comment: @vard `FromCities` and `ToCities` are two aliases, an alias is a new name you give to the table, then you can call this table with this new name. These two new aliases names, make you can select the from and to cities from the two cities tables, they are the same table but with two different aliases names.

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal, how to create this aliases?

Comment: @vard To create an alias, just put its name after the table name like `OriginalTableName AS TableAlias` the `AS` keyword is optional, you can omit it like `OriginalTableName TableAlias`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT f.FlightName, f.City_From, f.City_To
FROM Tbl_Flights f
```

would be the most basic which would list each flight and what city it goes from and which city it goes to.

Let me know if you need a more complex return from your query tho, I will be happy to help.

edit:

After looking at the extra info I think the following should match what you want:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d32c/17 so Mahmoud Gamal seems to have been pretty spot on:)

```
SELECT f.FlightName, c.CityName as 'from', c1.CityName as 'to'
FROM Tbl_Flights f
join Tbl_Cities c on c.cityid = f.City_From 
join Tbl_Cities c1 on c1.cityid = f.City_To
```

Comment: Yes, I need.. f.City_From is a f.City_To key values for cities, I want to have city names for this values from other table

Comment: whats the second table called and contain?

Comment: For example it called `Tbl_Cities` and contains fields `Key` and `City_name`. Key field is linked with `City_From` and `City_To` fields from table containing flights.

Comment: Tbl_flights contains flihgtname, fromkey and tokey?